# C# Project ObservableCollection

Tags: c#

I have inherited a C# project and really stumped on how to go about fixing an issue.

Basically i have a class that spawns a new comms thread. This comms thread receives data and simply adds this data to a ObservableCollection as a custom class.

The main class also starts another new thread and this processes the ObservableCollection, its basically a load of linq quires and depending on required combination etc triggers different things in the code. Its a continuous while loop with a small sleep after its done all the checks

Now its perfectly feasible this processing could take longer than the next message to come in hence why it doesn't take place in the message received trigger.

One of the first linq it does is Collection.where(....).OrderByDescending(....).ToList();

This is frequently giving me the error "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute" error.
Which makes sense, I'm reading whilst comms thread is writing to it.

Whats the best architecture for me to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

You could consider double buffering:

- you start off collecting messages in collection A
- when your processing thread starts, it directs the Comms task to collection B (locking required!).
- then it processes collection A and afterwards clears it.
- next time the processing threas starts, it directs the comms task to collection A before processing collection B, etc

PS: why are you using an `ObservableCollection`? You could e.g. use a simple list, since you don't seem to use any notification when a new message arrives